# VSCode how do I clear out the popup cache of things I've typed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to use VSCode and get work done and learning to do some UnitTesting but the intellisense seems to be picking up stuff that I've typed while trying to figure out things which are not valid options at all for unittesting.

How do I clear out my popup of this garbage?

It is just adding frustration to confusion at this point.[image: what is this mess]

Comment: Try disabling the setting: `Editor: Word Based Suggestion`. see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This definitely has gotten rid of a lot if not all of the junk i was seeing.